# I want to run a background process for internet checking in Android

Tags: android

I want a background process like async task which runs in the background. How to run internet connection checking as a background process in Android?

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: I know about connection dector class in java by which i can check the network likw wifi is enable or not,but i want to run this thing as a all tym background process. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to listen for Connectivity State Changes through a Broadcast Receiver.

in manifest register receiver:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Java class of Broadcast receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.d("app","Network connectivity change");
     if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
        NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            Log.i("app","Network "+ni.getTypeName()+" connected");
        } else if(intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE)) {
            Log.d("app","There's no network connectivity");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @androider.Can you explain how Boardcast receiver actually works as a background process?

Comment: It'll work whenever your connectivity changes in background.(like service but not for continuously like service). Broadcast Receiver only executes when this event occur.

Comment: Don't think so. This connectivity tells nothing about internet available.

Comment: @greenapps, whenever internet available or not, connectivity changes and thus in OnReceive we check for connectivity. This has been used on many places in android programming.

Comment: As i said: your code is not checking for internet connectivity.

Comment: then you can also hit any webservice there if network connectivity found, if status is 200, then internet is available. Do according to your needs. Thanks that's all folks right now.

Comment: Check links: https://gist.github.com/aniXification/5896231 ,http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I have updated the code**

Add the following permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Then Through this method you can know whether internet is available or not:

```
public boolean networktest() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;

        }
        if (haveConnectedWifi == false && haveConnectedMobile == false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Use a **async task** to regularly check for the **internet connection**:

```
class FooFailAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        try {
            while (!networktest()) {
                System.out.println("still not connected");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            System.out.println("mobile data or wifi connected");
            //do something after connecting mobile data or wifi
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "Working";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not aa background process.This is just a simple checking of network.

Comment: you can invoke this function in a async task...
it will become a background process

Comment: No actually i want a background service while always run when my app is onresume state

Comment: Thanks for updating your ans i will definitely look into ur code and let you know soon